# How many languages the Wp7 Keyboard support and How to SetUp

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, internationalization

I wish to create a translation app for Windows Phone 7. I am not sure how to go about it. Here the questions.

I like to know when I input text into a TextBox for translation, how do I do it?

1) Say, my Windows phone is Chinese. How do I change it to other languages like France, German, Russian and other?  I want to type in German to learn.

Example :  Type in German and translate to Japanese? How to set my phone for  German input ?

2) Is language input thru Keyboard defined by the region?

Say, if user buy the phone in Europe, the keyboard for input like German,France and other are already setup?

`textBox  inputScope ="Text"` This will show all the european languages?

3) How To detect or find out how many languages that the Windows Phone keyboard can support for input.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. Currently you cannot do this in code - system settings are outside the designated development sandbox. The user will be able to switch between keyboard layouts manually as long as those are present on the device.
2. Depending on the region where the phone is sold, the keyboard layouts are preset specifically for the designated zones. So that would be a yes - the **Text** InputScope will be active for registered languages.
3. Currently there is no way you can get a list of available keyboard layouts on your device.